# checkbox operation in jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

I am trying this one to solve since last night but could not hence asking for help.

There are two pages, such as `name.jsp` and `roll.jsp`. In `name.jsp` there are two input text boxes and one checkbox.I entered data in two text boxes and i checked the check box , when i checked the check box i am going to `roll.jsp` and in `roll.jsp` 2 text boxes are present.

When I reached `roll.jsp` by clicking checkbox, I kept the link(`name.jsp`) on `roll.jsp` page and when i am clicking `name.jsp` I am not able to see my previously entered data on two textboxes. How can i achieve this? I am going to roll.jsp through a checkbox and i want to see all my previously entered data on `name.jsp` when i am clicking `name.jsp` hyperlink which is present in `roll.jsp`. How to achieve it? Two different forms are in these two pages.

Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

When you have navigated away from page, all its input data will be lost. To remain it, you have to carry the data over either by request or through saving the data in a database/localstorage.

OR

You can try to use an iframe/SPA kind of behaviour. Where roll.jsp is loaded within the name.jsp either by iframe or using AJAX to bring in the content. That way you would not have navigated away from the page and thus the input data can still be used.

Answer (score 0):

On event of click, if that `checkbox` is checked, make a call for `roll.jsp`, which will submit the value of current 2 `textbox` as well as it will show in `roll.jsp`.

For showing the previously entered values, accept using `request.getParameter(string)` and print that in `roll.jsp`.

Whatever the response will come from `roll.jsp`, print that is one div.

Hope your problem is solved.

Comment: have u done it in ur app? please answer if you know the exact solution

Comment: I will not say "YES", but this is simplest way to do this thing. I am confirm about this solution.